Parameterizable/generic Verilog functions
I need to port a large (synthesizable) VHDL-93 code library to Verilog-2005.
I'm very familiar with VHDL, but new to Verilog.
Many things map clearly between the two languages, but I'm completely stuck with functions. In particular, I have many dozens of VHDL functions which operate on vectors of arbitrary length and I can't find a way to do the same thing in Verilog.
For the sake of an example, imagine a VHDL function that reverses the bits in a vector, like this:
function reverse(a : in std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
  variable result : std_logic_vector(a'RANGE);
  alias aa : std_logic_vector(a'REVERSE_RANGE) is a;
begin
  for i in aa'RANGE loop
    result(i) := aa(i);
  end loop;
  return result;
end;

It seems like SystemVerilog can perhaps achieve something similar using either a static function inside a virtual class or with scary-looking pre-processor macros. But I haven't been able to find anything for Verilog-2005.
As far as I understand, Verilog functions do not support parameters (like Verilog modules do) and they don't support unbounded vectors. So, how would a Verilog user approach this problem? Would they instantiate a different (parameterized) module for each function call? Or is there a better way?
I did search the specific example of bit-reversal, but every ... single ... answer I found suggested some variation of an inline generate for loop (or had hard-coded bit-widths). My functions are called hundreds of times in the code library, so I certainly don't want to replace every clean function call with a blob of messy code.

Minimal Verilog example
My best attempt was this reverse function inside a reverser module. This at least is parameterizable via the module parameter WIDTH. But I don't think I really want a module... I just want the function.
module reverser
#(
    parameter WIDTH = 5
)
(
    input wire [WIDTH-1:0] x,
    output wire [WIDTH-1:0] y
);

    function [WIDTH-1:0] reverse(
        input [WIDTH-1:0] data
    );
    integer i;
    begin
        for (i=0; i < WIDTH; i=i+1) begin
            reverse[WIDTH-1-i] = data[i];
        end
    end
    endfunction

    assign y = reverse(x);
endmodule


@Harry Static function inside a virtual class is supported by synthesis tools. Why limit yourself to Verilog-2005, which was 25 years ago?

@dave_59 The short answer is that my boss told me so. The reason is that we need a (large) subset of these functions to be compatible with legacy Verilog-2005 code. As far as I understand, it's not possible to import SystemVerilog classes in old Verilog modules.

@dave_59 The "25 years ago" point went over my head. I guess Verilog didn't change much between 1999 and 2005?

@Mikef We use all major FPGA toolchains (particularly AMD/Xilinx, Altera/Intel/Altera, Microchip and Lattice) ... from current versions, and stretching back 10+ years. We don't target any ASIC toolchains ourselves, but the code might be shared with people who want to do that. VHDL-93 is reasonably well supported in all those cases (VHDL-2008 isn't). Is toolchain support for SystemVerilog likely to be a problem?

A few thoughts:

I would navigate this comment by changing to an all SV design:


it's not possible to import SystemVerilog classes in old Verilog modules.

Compile the legacy Verilog files (.v) as SystemVerilog (.sv) by simply changing the file extensions.  Verilog is 100% forward compatible into SystemVerilog.
Now you have a SystemVerilog design and you are able to use the static function in a virtual class and the parameterized function behavior is available.


Check the support of whatever synthesis tool you are using for support of ' Static function inside a virtual class'.   I know its supported in recent versions of Vivado ug901-vivado-synthesis guide.

I am only aware of Xilinx, but would expect Altera to also support because they are competitors and try to leap-frog each other for features/performance etc.  Other vendors may lag in SV support.  Some vendors provide Synplicity licenses others have their own tool; they may not provide a full-featured Synplicity license when doing this; Synopsys likes revenue also.  You will need to research this.


Maybe dry-run a small design with a couple of simple functions, then examine the post synthesis schematic to see that it works as expected to gain confidence and buy-in to the approach.


Portability of this code library (between FPGA vendors and toolchains) is really important. That's why the VHDL version is still fully VHDL-93 compliant. I'm sensing there is no quick solution in Verilog, so I'll just have to suffer through it. (As a side note, the whole library also needs to be ported to SystemVerilog, so your comments are still helpful). Most likely, we will tackle SystemVerilog first ... I'm slightly dreading the Verilog.

It would be good for your career to learn Verilog. and SV to expert level.

I checked your link for the 2018.3 version of Xilinx UG901 and on p274, it states that classes are "not supported". So, I checked the latest (2023.2) version and on p289 it states that while some aspects of SystemVerilog classes are supported, virtual classes are not. Do you recall how you worked around this?

Sorry for the trouble. I had looked it up & thought it was supported. Use regular functions\w wide inputs, & mask inputs, then mask as needed. If you need 8 bit inputs create 32 bit input generic functions and set the mask to be 8. In the function use the mask to sent bits 9-32 = 0. This will not work for every possible scenario, but will work for some. Verilog is not strongly typed; you can drive a large bus with a small one and vice versa. Take advantage of weak typing. Verilog sign extends or zero extends small buses onto larger busses & chops busses larger than the assignment target.

What is wrong with your 'module' example. In v2k the only place where you can define a function is inside a module. So, you would need a module in any case.
The only problem would be if you need multiple functions with different parameters in the same module. But this can be solved using generate blocks. Here is an example:
module A(y8, y12, y16, data8, data12, data16);
  output wire[7:0] y8;
  output wire[11:0] y12;
  output wire[15:0] y16;
  input wire[7:0] data8;
  input wire[11:0] data12;
  input wire[15:0] data16;
  
  
  genvar WIDTH;
  for (WIDTH = 8; WIDTH <= 16; WIDTH = WIDTH + 4) begin: def
    function [WIDTH-1:0] reverse(
        input [WIDTH-1:0] data
    );
    integer i;
    begin
        for (i=0; i < WIDTH; i=i+1) begin
            reverse[WIDTH-1-i] = data[i];
        end
    end
    endfunction
  end
  
  assign y8 = def[8].reverse(data8);
  assign y12 = def[12].reverse(data12);
  assign y16 = def[16].reverse(data16);
endmodule

Just make sure that def[8].reverse.. is supported by the tools you use.
Macros are also not so scary and sometimes such a solution is  not too bad and is more flexible than with genblocks or parameterized modules.
  `define REVERSE(WIDTH, y, data)\
    always @* begin:wdt_``WIDTH\
      reg [WIDTH-1:0] tmp_reversed;\
      integer i;\
      for (i=0; i < WIDTH; i=i+1) begin \
        tmp_reversed[WIDTH-1-i] = data[i];\
      end\
    end\
    assign y = wdt_``WIDTH.tmp_reversed;

  
  `REVERSE(8, y8, data8)
  `REVERSE(12, y12, data12)
  `REVERSE(16, y16, data16)


What is wrong with your 'module' example? It just seems like a horrific amount of overhead to achieve a very simple goal. Thanks for your examples. They both contain several magic numbers (8, 12 and 16). These would, of course, need to be parameters of the module A. Would they still work in that case?

Also, will the macro work if the same parameterization is used twice within the same scope? I don't quite follow the code (particularly the always @* begin:wdt_``WIDTH\ part) ... but I sense there may be a risk of a name clash here somewhere.

As you can see from the macro, the variables are declared inside a named block, which name is built based on the width parameter: wdt_8, wdt_16, ... This prevents from name collision if actions differ by width. If this is not enough, the name could be built differently to avoid collisions for the same width.
